# How to print json value in python

Tags: python, json

I have this json value and want print the number for day. Am able to print the content for the android json value but I want to print only the value for the day which is `70` .

```
import json
import requests


json_data = [
    {
        "name": "Android",
        "classification": "public",
        "detail": "Tag1, Tag2, Tag3",
        "days": 70,
        "date_last": "2017-07-21 05:48:07 AM"
    },
    {
        "name": "iPhone",
        "classification": "public",
        "detail": "Tag4, Tag5, Tag6",
        "days": 75,
        "date_last": "2017-07-21 05:48:07 AM"
    },
    {
        "name": "Microsoft",
        "classification": "public",
        "detail": "Tag3, Tag8, Tag9",
        "days": 90,
        "date_last": "2017-07-21 05:48:07 AM"
    }
]


output = [x for x in json_data if x["name"]=="Android"]
print(output)
```

This is my result with the above code

```
[{'name': 'Android', 'classification': 'public', 'detail': 'Tag1, Tag2, Tag3', 'days': 70, 'date_last': '2017-07-21 05:48:07 AM'}]
```

Comment: So, obviously you know how to access the value for specific key, what is the problem to access the value for key `days`? It's another question if you have to use list comprehension or regular loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which part of the object you want to add to the output array. In your case this is fairly simple. Just add specify the key (in this case days).
It should look like this:

```
output = [x["days"] for x in json_data if x["name"]=="Android"]
```